# Transplant Shock in Rose plant

Tags: houseplants

[image][image][image]I have purchased rose plant from nursery.

[image]

But it has black spots on the stem. I have already applied systemic and contact fungicide. Now I Transplanted it 7 days ago [image]now all the leaves have fallen.How to solve this problem?

[image]

Any suggestions

Comment: Just a thought - you seem to have a rather liberal approach when it comes to applying fungicide. And see declining plants. Have you considered that you may be doing too much?

Comment: @Stephie I agree with you, and perhaps that's what killing OP's most plants, when they aren't in need of the fungicide, the more and the needless does more harm than all the good.

Comment: One time fungicide applied

Comment: For die back I applied fungicide

Comment: @Sunild The thing is such that, you shouldn't always be applying fungicides. As also, not with that proportion you administer. Fungicides should be left for application explicitly after pruning your plants or if your plants show the symptoms of fungal diseases. I can understand that you care a lot for plants and are willing to take precautions so as not allow them to catch fungal diseases. However,  application of fungicides at such a rate does more harm than good. Apply only after pruning or if they show symptoms of infection and refer to pamphlet provided for correct dosage.

Comment: Contact fungicides are more corrosive and can extensively damage your foliage. Your Vinca succumbed to fungicide burn. Don't let the same mistake catch up on you every now and them. Plants are resilient creatures and probably don't do well with overcaring and overapplications.

Comment: I removed a rose from that branch. So I applied fungicide on cutting.

Comment: @Jayparth is it necessary to cover vinca plant till shoots grow or not please reply

Comment: @Sunild Considering you are a beginner with humidification and delayed a bit with Vincas they succumbed to environment shock, and your fungicide proportion further alleviated the burns on tender foliage tissues. I previously assumed that you might be familiar with techniques of humidification, so I didn't gave very detailed information on the same and was abstract in description. Next time if you ever attempt to humidify, try it with wettened cloth bags instead of plastic bags till you learn the technique. Don't ever water your plants soils undergoing humidification after watering it once.

Comment: By cloth bags for learning technique, I mean one of these:- https://dl.flipkart.com/s/WRfczRNNNN    Secondly, if your humidification bags start drying off, spray lightly on the leaves or the surface of cloth bag instead of watering the soil. And the last point you missed is acclimatization of your newly budded plants. You pulled off your bag altogether instead of slowly acclimatizing your plants. This gave them environmental shock. I'll leave you few vids:-  1.) https://youtu.be/eV2j-iiSmD0?si=vJBh9WosdaxrSzcK  and 2.) https://youtu.be/dTrVgKSPmA8?si=D6nb_0qC8frBDw_3

Comment: Conducting the same experiment with your rose may help you understand a few points as I've saw people doing the same with Apples, pears and almonds all of them belong to the same Rosaceae family (Rose family). But excercise caution and see that you learn to amend the point of acclimatization first. Another great video (on humidification experiment and that too on roses) here: https://youtu.be/OJAIDTQ-_u0?si=8IzIdFgLNWqWSpdR

Comment: @Jayparth  thanks for your information.

Comment: @Jayparth as you said I have placed the rose plant in cotton bag for humidification I have attached photo.

Comment: @Sunild Good effort! Also don't forget about acclimatization.

Comment: @Jayparth Okay thank you for your information.

Comment: Also, the bags should be misted from inside, not just outside.

Comment: @Jayparth Misting inside may I have to remove bag each day?

Comment: @Sunild that's the whole point of acclimatization. You remove the bag for a few hours and allow the plant to get adapted to local conditions. As also, you spray the insides of the bag and re-bag it after few hours. Repeat this process every day till new sprouts emerge.

Comment: The few hours could be between 2-5 hours every day without covered bag. And never acclimatize your plant in direct sun, choose partial sun or shade instead.

Comment: @Jayparth thank you for your information.